# Flatness of the forgetful map of moduli space for smooth curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let's work over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C)$. Given $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ as the moduli space of smooth curves of genus with $n$ marks and $\epsilon:\overline{M}_{g,n}\to\overline{M}_{g,n-1}$ the morphism that forgets the last mark.

Assume that $n+2g>3$ (so that $\overline{M}_{g,n-1}$ exists) is the map flat?

First, it is true for $g=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". Intuitively the fibers of these maps all have dimension 1, so one might expect flatness, for the genus 0 case this actually constitutes a proof, since the forgetful maps are dominant morphisms of smooth schemes, so constant fiber dimension implies flatness.

How to see the result in general really depends on your point of view. (I'm assuming you're regarding $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ as a stack, but you can also think about its coarse moduli space instead).

If you understand $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ as the solution to the moduli problem of flat families of stable genus $g$ curves with $n$ marked points, then flatness of the forgetting maps is essentially tautological. The universal family over $\overline{M}_{g,n}$ is automatically flat, and is naturally identified with the forgetting map $\overline{M}_{g,n+1}\to \overline{M}_{g,n}$. Since we're working in characteristic 0, this implies the same result about the coarse moduli spaces.

Comment: Does “fibers of  a map all have the same dimension" implies flatness?

Comment: Not in general, but as I said in the answer, it does in the case of Deligne-Mumford spaces. (See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry for more details). 

I phrased the response the way I did because constancy of fiber dimension is a common "intuitive model" for flatness.

Comment: So the smoothness of the schemes are kinda needed?

Comment: Flatness implies constancy of fiber dimension, the theorem mentioned in the link in my comment gives a condition for the reverse to be true. This relies both on some control over the singularities of the source and target, and the morphism being dominant.